# Blender's version of Sketchup's line tool?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

(I previously opened a multi question thread, which is against rules, so here's just the main question I had)

As a relatively long term Sketchup user I can't work without the line tool and the Knife tool in Blender doesn't show distance and it doesn't snap by length like the Sk-u line tool, so it's really hard to work with it.

Basically here's what I want to do, to draw a small line 20cm from ,,point Q" (random name I thought of) and then to draw a line towards the other side of the box to the point that is also 20 cm from it's version of "point Q", hopefully **without** using subdivision and loop tool, which both create a lot of unnecessary things and are both unprecise for what I need.

[image]

I was advised previosly to use the snap utilities addon, but I only want to use either Blender's own stuff or at least a freely available addon (snap utilities is 17 usd), I am a 21 year old from east europe, so I neither have (or need) a credit card, nor a paypal and I'm not in the mood to get those 2 just for a small snapping addon, I'd probably end up paying a lot more for the credit card itself..., so if there is anything free, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Blender isn't really the right tool for doing precision 3D design, but it can be done.

You will have to do some arithmetic, but one approach would be

- start with a view perpendicular to the face you want the edge on.  In your example, it looks like that would be top orthographic, so hit NUMPAD-7
- select the knife tool (Shortcut KKEY)
- place the cursor on the either of the edges you want to connect and click LMB
- type the C key
- place the cursor on the other edge and click LMB
- type ENTER

This will create the edge you want, but not place it where you want it.

- type g
- do not move your mouse
- Go to transform panel of the properties panel and enter a value.  (if the properties panel is not visible, type N to unhide it) the transform panel looks like

[image]

To figure out the value, here is an example, based on your image.
* You appear to be adding the edge to a top face.  This means that you want to set the median y value entry.
* take the y value of point q and subtract 20cm from it.
* enter the result.

You end up with a precisely place edge.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, old-school style, no add-ons

Assuming you want your 20cm to be in the X direction (If not, you would set a custom orientation on a perpendicular edge,) and assuming your units are set to meters.

1. <kbd>K</kbd> cut an edge from anywhere to anywhere on the top face
2. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slide the line to collapse it to the reference edge
3. Hit <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0.2</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the people at Blender Foundation are having a focus...

Still, in this case, I would subdivide two edges, select the new edge and press <kbd>G</kbd> twice. Then you can easily type in 0.8 and get exactly what you want...
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might be of interest to you

**THE LINE TOOL FROM THIS ADDON IS ALREADY IN BLENDER 2.79**

[image: S]
[image: R]
**Or this alternate method**
[image: t]

https://blendermarket.com/products/snap-utilities

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7EoY2Hy5G8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLQVEK2HgQ0

Comment: That is not necessary for the functionality that the question is about. It can be done without any add-ons with a few clicks. One can use Rip Fill function(alt+v hovering the mouse away from the edge in the direction the edge should be split), this can be followed by x, y or z to chose the axis for transform and 0.2 can be typed as numerical input during the transform operation to move it 0.2 of a meter if meters are the units set in the scene settings.

Comment: The Line tool from this addon already comes with Blender 2.79, Just have to activate it

Comment: Yes, but this is the most basic numerical input with transform operators functionality we are talking about. It does not make much sense to use add-ons instead of it the way I see it. The very basic way to move objects in Blender works like that already. I am sure the add-on might be useful for other things, but it is not very relevant to the question.

Comment: @Racko Interesting, could you add more info to the question about how to activate the tool? As it is it's pretty unclear, and besides, links go down over time.

Comment: Yeah I updated showing how to activate it, its basically already in your Addons. Or here https://i.imgur.com/1wsfQRw.gif  It doesnt show measurements live but it can **parallel snap** and **draw lines** which **Knife tool cannot**